# Scrape Information from HTML using VBA

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

```
<div class="game_content">

                <div class="game_table">
                    <article class="league_name">
                        <span class="flags flags-category flags--uefa-europa-league"></span>
                        <h6 class="hide-on-small-only hide-on-med-only hide_ipadLand"><a title="International">International</a></h6>
                        <h3><a href="/en/league-games/1/uefa-europa-league" title="UEFA Europa League">UEFA Europa League</a></h3>
                    </article>                    <div class="game_detailsCol">
                        <div class="col s2 m1 l1">
                            <span class="red-text"><span class="green-text bold">F</span><span class="grey-text">21:45</span></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s3 m4 l5">
                            <div>
                                <p class="yellow_card">3</p>
                            </div>
                            <a href="/en/teams/Marseille" title="Marseille livescore">Marseille</a>
                        </div>

                                                            <div class="col s1 m1 l1">
                                    <a href="/en/game-info/467162/marseille-atletico-madrid" title="Marseille-Atletico Madrid livescore" class="">
                                        0-3                                    </a>
                                </div>



                        <div class="col s3 m4 l5">
                            <a href="/en/teams/Atletico+Madrid" title="Atletico Madrid livescore">Atletico Madrid</a>
                            <div>
                                <span class="grey-text">0-1</span>
                                <p class="yellow_card">2</p>                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s2 m1 l1">
                                                        <i class="icon icon-star " game_id="467162"></i>
                            <a class="dropdown-button hide-on-small-only hide-on-med-only hide_ipadLand" data-activates="dropdown467162">
                                <i class="icon icon-more_vert"></i>
                            </a><ul id="dropdown467162" class="dropdown-content">
                                <li class="close_dropMenu"><strong>x</strong></li>
                                                                <li><a href="/en/h2h/467162/marseille-atletico-madrid" title="Head To Head">Head To Head</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Guys,

I'm new in scraping information from websites via VBA so help is needed.
i want to loop through div class="game_content" and in each div class="game_table" scrap the below info:

```
FROM title="UEFA Europa League" GET "UEFA Europa League"
FROM title="Marseille livescore">Marseille GET "Marseille"
FROM title="Marseille-Atletico Madrid livescore" class="">0-3 GET 0-3
FROM title="Atletico Madrid livescore">Atletico Madrid GET Atletico Madrid
FROM <span class="grey-text">0-1</span> GET 0-1
```

My post includes the FIRST class="game_table FROM class="game_content"

My piece of code:

```
Sub InternetConnection()

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDocument As HTMLDocument
    Dim GameList As IHTMLElement
    Dim Games As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Game As IHTMLElement

    'Open Internet Explorer
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate ("https://azscore.com/en/yesterday")            
        Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE   
            Application.StatusBar = "Loading..."
        Loop

   Set HTMLDocument = IE.document   
   Set GameList = HTMLDocument.getElementsByClassName("game_content")(0)
   Set Games = GameList.Children       

    For Each Game In Games
        If Game.className = "game_table" Then
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required references via tools > references

1. HTML Object Library
2. MS Internet Controls.

Note:

Different output as now run on a different day against the website.

---

### ① Here is a version that parses out just those items:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PrintMatchInfo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer, doc As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://azscore.com/en/yesterday"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set doc = .document
    End With

    Dim games As Object, i As Long, j As Long, counter As Long
    counter = 1

    Set games = doc.getElementsByClassName("game_table")

    For i = 0 To games.Length - 1

        For j = 0 To games(i).getElementsByClassName("game_detailsCol").Length - 1
           With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
               .Cells(counter, 1) = Split(games(i).innerText, Chr$(10))(3)
               Dim tempArr() As String
               tempArr() = Split(GetKeyDetails(ReplacedString(games(i).getElementsByClassName("game_detailsCol")(j).innerText)), Chr$(126))
               .Cells(counter, 2).Resize(1, UBound(tempArr) + 1) = tempArr
               counter = counter + 1
            End With
        Next j

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Public Function ReplacedString(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\s{2,}"
    End With
    ReplacedString = regex.Replace(str, Chr$(126)) '<== or other unexpected character
End Function


Public Function GetKeyDetails(ByVal inputString As String) As String
    Dim regex As Object, tempString As String
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "(^[A-Z](?:\d|[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d~)(\d?~?)+" '"^[A-Z](?:\d|[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d~(\d~)?(\d~)?|x\~Head To Head"
    End With

    tempString = regex.Replace(inputString, vbNullString)

    Dim tempArr() As String

    tempArr = Split(tempString, Chr$(126))

    Dim keyDetails(), outputString As String, detail As Long
    keyDetails = Array(0, 1, 2, 3)

    For detail = LBound(keyDetails) To UBound(keyDetails)
        outputString = outputString & Chr$(126) & tempArr(keyDetails(detail))
    Next detail

    GetKeyDetails = Trim$(outputString)

End Function
```

Output:

### [image: Output]

### ② Version with all the info:

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub PrintAllMatchInfo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer, doc As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = New InternetExplorer

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://azscore.com/en/yesterday"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set doc = .document
    End With

    Dim games As Object, i As Long, j As Long, counter As Long
    counter = 1

    Set games = doc.getElementsByClassName("game_table")

    For i = 0 To games.Length - 1

        For j = 0 To games(i).getElementsByClassName("game_detailsCol").Length - 1
           With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
               .Cells(counter, 1) = Split(games(i).innerText, Chr$(10))(3)
               .Cells(counter, 2) = ReplacedString(games(i).getElementsByClassName("game_detailsCol")(j).innerText)
               counter = counter + 1
            End With
        Next j

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Public Function ReplacedString(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\s{2,}"
    End With
    ReplacedString = regex.Replace(str, " ") '<== or other unexpected character
End Function
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Pattern for your follow-up question: `"^\w+\/(\d+~)+"`

Comment: Dear QHarr do you receive my messages in the chat?

Comment: @QHarr a quick question.For Web Scrapping i use the following references with the below order:

Visual Basic For Applications (Excel default References)
Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library (Excel default References)
Microsoft HTML Object Library (Added)
OLE Automation (Excel default References)
Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library (Excel default References)
Microsoft Internet Controls (Added)
Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library (Added)

Is there a specific order for the above references?

Comment: No. I think they are listed alphabetically. And the ones you select move to the top. Which you need depends on what you are doing and the dependant libraries. For what you have listed 3 I use in relation to web-scraping: one for HTML objects e.g. HTMLDocument (HTML Object Library), one for automating IE (Internet Controls) and one for using the clipboard (Forms). Ticking them makes the associated library available to the project.

Comment: When i download the document (with the code) in a new pc i need to enable editing and all this security alerts.when i finish with the alerts and execute the code i receive an error error on line: Set IE = New InternetExplorer.after closing and re opening the doc the code works fine.any ideas?

Comment: What is the error code? Also, rather than fill the comments here you can discuss with me in the [dawghaus](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus) or post a question